# How to modify this tkinter GUI code to include classes and methods?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, user-interface, tkinter

I have a fully functioning tkinter GUI (or so it seems...) but I would like to clean up the code a bit by creating classes and methods for those classes. Would someone be able to go through this code and re-organise it into classes and methods so it still functions in the same way, but if possible could you also annotate/ include notes to a certain degree? I would like this to be a learning experience for me as well.

One other thing that is causing an issue in the program is python freezing when I try to use the quit button. I don't believe this is a result of the quit button code because python had the same issue when I simply closed the GUI window prior to adding the quit function. Is this a result of me being on a mac, and perhaps some functioning issues related to that? Or is this an issue that can be resolved in my code?

On a side note to this: If anyone knows of any cool aesthetic things I can do with a GUI on a mac please answer with ideas! This program currently starts at a main window that has a descriptive label, a combobox of graph options, a button that launches a new window with the selected graph to look at concerning the data this is modeled off of, a gif that adds some pzazz to the window, and a quit button. I am using the arc theme which has made it look nicer, but would welcome any suggestions or ideas, in particular with graphing because I only really have the data to make bar graphs it seems but would love to be making bubble plots or something cool like that if I could do so with discrete, qualitative data.

Thanks for any help!

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

final_year_totals_df = get_totals_df(df, "Service Year")
regional_totals_df = get_totals_df(df, "Location")
ethnicity_totals_df = get_totals_df(df, "Ethnicity")
age_totals_df = get_totals_df(df, "Age band")
service_type_totals_df = get_service_df(df)
top_10_types_df = get_top_10(service_type_totals_df)
cause_totals_df = get_totals_df(df, "Cause of injury")
top_10_causes_df = get_top_10(cause_totals_df)

def pick_graphs():
    graph = ACC_combo.get()
    result = None
    title = None
    if graph == "Service Year":
        result = final_year_totals_df
        title = "ACC Concussion Claims by Year 2010-2019"
    elif graph == "Service Type":
        result = top_10_types_df
        title = "ACC Concussion Claims for Top 10 Treatment Service Types 2010-2019"
    elif graph == "Cause of Injury":
        result = top_10_causes_df
        title = "ACC Concussion Claims for Top 10 Causes of Injury 2010-2019"
    elif graph == "Location":
        result = regional_totals_df
        title = "ACC Concussion Claims by Region 2010-2019"
    elif graph == "Age Band":
        result = age_totals_df
        title = "ACC Concussion Claims by Age Bracket 2010-2019"
    elif graph == "Ethnicity":
        result = ethnicity_totals_df
        title = "ACC Concussion Claims by Ethnicity 2010-2019"
    return result, title

def display_graph():
    window = tk.Toplevel()
    window.geometry("1500x1200")

    style = ThemedStyle(window)
    style.set_theme("arc")

    graph, title = pick_graphs()
    fig = Figure(figsize = (3,3), dpi = 100)
    fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0.2)
    a = fig.add_subplot(111)
    a.xaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    a.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none')
    a.xaxis.set_tick_params(pad=5)
    a.yaxis.set_tick_params(pad=10)
    a.grid(b=True, color='grey', linestyle='-.', linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.2)
    a.set_title(title, loc='left', pad=10)
    graph.plot(kind='barh', legend=False, ax=a, color='crimson')

    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, window)
    toolbar.update()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

    exit_button = Button(window, text = "Back To Main", command = window.destroy)
    exit_button.pack()


def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()


root = Tk()
root.title('ACC Concussion Data 2010-2019')
root.geometry("600x500")

style = ThemedStyle(root)
style.set_theme("arc")

root_label = Label(root, text = 'Welcome to my GUI!' + '\n' + 
               'Please select the variable you would like to explore from the menu options below.' + 
               '\n' + 'The resulting pop-up window will display an interactive graph of a specific 
               aspect' + '\n' + 'of the data compiled by the ACC about concussion claims filed from 
               2010-2019.')
root_label.pack(side=TOP)

graph_button = Button(root, text = "Graph it!", command = display_graph)
graph_button.pack()

quit_button = Button(root, text="Exit", command=_quit)
quit_button.pack(side=BOTTOM)


ACC_combo = Combobox(root, values = ["Service Year", "Service Type", "Cause of Injury", 
                                                  "Location", "Age Band", "Ethnicity"])
ACC_combo.set("Service Year")
ACC_combo.pack()

photo = PhotoImage(file = "/Users/oscarevans/Desktop/concussion_GIF.gif")
label = Label(image = photo)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It seems you are asking for a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't exactly see what you want done here. There are MANY ways something could operate in a class with methods. Usually, you do this when the class architecture helps your code operate, helps you build the code or helps others to read the code.  This code seems to have been successful in those regards so it's hard for me to come up with a good class structure for you. If you have some goal in mind other than just to use classes, feel free to explain, and I will try to work with you.  As for the quit button; yeah tk and mac have a weird thing...does it work if you delete everything but root?

Comment: The idea behind re-writing this with classes is that the course I am learning python through emphasises using object oriented programming with classes when using tkinter and GUI's because it is considered good form. However, I haven't quite got the hang of using classes like I have task oriented programming - hence why I could get this going without classes. So the purpose of the restructuring is to help me better understand how to implement classes. As for the root question, no, nothing happens when I only have root in the program, the code will run without error but python doesn't launch GUI